# SlackWebhook Is it possibible to send a msg with a custom name?

Tags: webhooks, slack-api, slack

Send message via Slack Webhook with custom name?

I want to send a message in Slack via the API.
I'm using GPedro Slack Webhook for Java.
Is it possible to send it with a custom name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a simple message in with a custom name like this

```
SlackApi api = new SlackApi("https://hooks.slack.com/services/id_1/id_2/token");
api.call(new SlackMessage("#general", "Custom Name", "my message"));
```

For further information seek:
https://github.com/gpedro/slack-webhook#basic-examples

Comment: Sorry it was so easy!